# php получить доступ к методу protected у объекта

Tags: php

Есть объект некого класса "A", нужно вывести его свойство и вызвать метод.

php выдает ошибку, что нет доступа к этим методам т.к. они pretected.

как получить доступ?

Comment: Я так понимаю создать свой класс и наследовать от класса "А", но что делать дальше?

Comment: дальше использовать в коде ваш новый класс, и определить в нем метод который вызывает ваш protected метод.

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов у вас несколько.

- 1) наследование (создать новый класс наследовав базовый). При
  наследовании сможете делать "что угодно", переопределять методы,
  вызывать protected и т.д.
- 2) воспользоваться рефлекцией. При рефлексии вы можете получить
  названия методов и свойств но всеравно не сможете вызвать protected
  метод.
- 3) воспользоваться одним из шаблонов проектирования для таких задач,
  пытаюсь вспомнить его название....

Comment: Спасибо, попробую описать ситуацию:

Есть событие function before($obj) {
    
}

параметр $obj - это объект класса Events, у которого есть поле result (массив) - protected.

нужно в событии получить к нему доступ.

Я пытаюсь наследовать:

class myClass extends Events {
  public function A() {
      print_r($this->result);
   }
}


$q = new myClass;
$q->A();

Естественно выводит пустой результат, т.к. я обращаюсь напрямую к свойству класса не к свойству объекта. Как к объекту обратиться?

Comment: в комментариях подобные вещи не принято описывать. обновите отпик с приведением примера и оформите код как положено плз.